# Parsing, securing python expression before passing it to eval()

Tags: python

I want to take an input from the user may be like `foo() > 90 and boo() == 9 or do() > 100` and use eval on the server side to to evaluate this expression.

For security I want to restrict user to add limited functions and operators by keeping a check (against some data-structure) before I pass it to eval function.

PS: Input comes from a web page

Thanks

Comment: Parse it the same way a Python interpreter would?

Answer (score 3):

Basically the only way to do this is to parse it yourself. You navigate the parse tree to guarantee that each part is in a whitelist of perfectly benign and safe operations, making the entire expression safe by construction. Ned Batchelder's answer is actually a (simple) form of this. You could pass it to `eval()` after that, although, what would be the point? You could compute the value of each subexpression as part of verification (this is especially a good idea because it makes your parser resistant to changes in Python syntax and so on). This whitelist must be extremely tiny, and there are a lot of things that you might think are okay, but aren't (e.g. general call operator; getattr function). You have to be very careful.

A blacklist is absolutely out of the question (such as the suggestion to "reject suspicious entries"). Reject anything that is not obviously good. If you don't, it will be trivial to work around your filter and give an expression that does something bad, barring the unlikely possibility that your code is better than any other blacklisting filter for Python ever created.

There have been attempts at restricting Python execution, one is the infamous and now-disabled (because it didn't work) [rexec](http://docs.python.org/library/rexec.html) module (and company), and another is [PyPy's sandbox](http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/sandbox.html). This second option doesn't do exactly what you asked for, but it's certainly worth looking into. It's probably what I would use-- it just means that it won't be as easy as `eval(safematize(user_input))`.

Answer (score 1):

the more secure way is to do everything at the back end. Users just key in the necessary parameters. For example you can prompt them to key in numeric values for foo(), boo() and do(). Then at the back end, pass these values to appropriate functions to do the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest check would be to look at all the words in the expression, and check them against a whitelist.  Reject the expression if any of the words isn't on the whitelist.

```
import re

expr = "foo() > 90 and boo() == 9 or do() > 100"
whitelist = "and or foo boo do".split()
for word in re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]\w+", expr):
    if word not in whitelist:
        raise Exception("Warning! Warning!")
```

This works because you have a limited domain that you need users to be able to express themselves in, and also because I don't think there's a way to cause damage with eval without using identifiers.

You'll have to be careful that your whitelist doesn't inadvertently include possibly malicious Python identifiers, though.

Comment: You might do something a bit more elaborate than just splitting on non-word boundaries, so as to keep the parens on functions to identify them as functions?  keep functions, keywords (and special variables?) in separate pools.

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock down the input format, or it will be a gaping security hole.  Either implement a full blown parser, as lpthnc suggests, with a reasonable set of operations (but no more), or at least use a regular expression (or several regex patterns in a matching hierarchy and/or loop) to strip out recognized patterns, and reject suspicious entries as "not allowed".